# How to create button with text under icon using bootstrap 5 or css?

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I want to create the following buttons using Bootstrap 5 or my own CSS classes. How can I achieve that?

Examples:
[Set of buttons][1]

As you can see, some of them are working as a dropdown button.

I have been looking and I only have found examples with icon and text in the same line. Perhaps I have to use a Bootstrap Card?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V78lr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```css
.command-button {
  width: 85px; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  text-align: center; 
  background: #f8f9fa; 
  padding: 10px; 
  margin: 0px 3px;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; padding: 0px 15px;">
  <div class="command-button dropdown">
    <img src="" width="30" height="30" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <b class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownVisibilidad" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Visible
     </b>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownVisibilidad">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >Hacer visible</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >Hacer no visible</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="command-button">
    <img src="" width="30" height="30" style="margin: auto;">
    <b>Eliminar</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a div around your text and icon then setting `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` should do the trick

Comment: Okey, but how to put them in the same line? I want more than one button for line

Comment: One solution is to surround all the logo+text divs with another div with flex-direction set to row

Comment: nice, and to make act like a button? Hover, border ...

Comment: just use the ::hover selector and style it however you like add an href to link it somewhere